# VideoView (StagefrightPlayer) calls setDataSource() twice

Tags: android

I am playing back-to-back video with VideoView and I noticed that after the first time my code plays a video, StagefrightPlayer performs a setDataSource() to the previous file. Immediately afterwards it does a setDataSource() to the appropriate file.

**For example**

1st time a video is played:

```
I/Slideshow( 1206): showing video: video1
I/StagefrightPlayer(  876): setDataSource('/mnt/sdcard/cache/video1')
```

2nd time (and any afterwards) a video is played:

```
I/Slideshow( 1206): showing video: video2
I/StagefrightPlayer(  876): setDataSource('/mnt/sdcard/cache/video1')
I/StagefrightPlayer(  876): setDataSource('/mnt/sdcard/cache/video2')
```

code to play video:

```
        Log.i(TAG, "showing video: "+strfilename);
        final String strConstFilename = strfilename;
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), strConstFilename);
                mVideoView.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

                if (mOnCompletionListener != null)
                {
                    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnVideoCompletionListener());
                }
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                mVideoView.start();
            }
        });
```

It doesn't seem to break anything, but if I'm doing something wrong I'd like to correct the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the code in `VideoView.java`, the internal function `openVideo()` which actully does the `MediaPlayer.setDataSource` is called more than once, when you call `setVideoPath`, when the surface is created and in resume().

In this case, when you play the second time, i think the surface created callback comes first, so it uses the previous file path. Then your `setVideoPath` gets executed, so this time the correct file is used.

It works fine because, by the time you call `start`, the correct video file is set.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation :-) Sounds like a bug in Google's code